# How to add html attribute when using "semantic_form_for"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using "**semantic_form_for**" like following :

```
= semantic_form_for(@car) do |v|
  -v.inputs do
    =v.input :name
```

For this "**name**" input field, I would like to add more html attribute, how to do it within this "**semantic_form_for**" in Rails 3 ?

I tried `=v.input :name :html=>{:class=>'carname'}`, and `=v.input :name, :class=>'carname'`, but neither one works...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the [docs](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic)

> ...Customize HTML attributes for any input using the :input_html option...

```
=v.input :name, :input_html => { :class => 'carname' }
```

Answer (score 1):

`=v.input :name, :input_html=>{:class=>'carname'}`